# Split and Append "AND" between values

Tags: c#, split

how to split below value and append AND between values ?
I cannot Split with Space as there is spaces between words

```
"\"Mark John\" \"Tina Roy\""
as
"\"Mark John\" AND \"Tina Roy\""
```

In the end it should look like -

```
"Mark John" AND "Tina Roy"
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
string operatorValue = " AND ";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(operatorValue))
{
    foreach (string searchVal in SearchRequest.Text.Split(' '))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVal))
            searchValue += searchVal + operatorValue;
    }
}

int index = searchValue.LastIndexOf(operatorValue);

if (index != -1)
{
    outputSearchValue = searchValue.Substring(0, index);
}
```

Comment: use another seperator to deternmine name is ended or not.
or store names in array or Lists
after that, you can use String.Join to join elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use Regular Expressions:

```
var test = "\"John Smith\" \"Bill jones\" \"Bob Norman\"";      
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(test, "\" \"", "\" AND \""));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var result = str.Replace("\" \"","\" And \"");
```

If you have more than one name, or there is a possibility that you could have more than one whitespace between two names, you could opt for Regex.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str,"\"\\s+\"","\" And \"");
```

Example,

```
var str = "\"Mark John\"   \"Tina Roy\"   \"Anu Viswan\"";
var result = Regex.Replace(str,"\"\\s+\"","\" And \"");
```

Output

```
"Mark John" And "Tina Roy" And "Anu Viswan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting, replace the `" "` with `" AND "`

```
var test = "\"Mark John\" \"Tina Roy\"";
        var new_string= test.Replace("\" \"", " AND ");
```